# Error in defining Ackermann in Coq

Tags: coq, ackermann, totality

I am trying to define the Ackermann-Peters function in Coq, and I'm getting an error message that I don't understand. As you can see, I'm packaging the arguments `a, b` of Ackermann in a pair `ab`; I provide an ordering defining an ordering function for the arguments. Then I use the `Function` form to define Ackermann itself, providing it with the ordering function for the `ab` argument.

```
Require Import Recdef.    
Definition ack_ordering (ab1 ab2 : nat * nat) :=
    match (ab1, ab2) with
    |((a1, b1), (a2, b2)) => 
       (a1 > a2) \/ ((a1 = a2) /\ (b1 > b2))   
    end.
Function ack (ab : nat * nat) {wf ack_ordering} : nat :=
match ab with
| (0, b) => b + 1
| (a, 0) => ack (a-1, 1)
| (a, b) => ack (a-1, ack (a, b-1))
end.
```

What I get is the following error message:

> Error: No such section variable or assumption: `ack`.

I'm not sure what bothers Coq, but searching the internet, I found a suggestion there may be a problem with using a recursive function defined with an ordering or a measure, where the recursive call occurs within a match. However, using the projections `fst` and `snd` and an `if-then-else` generated a different error message. Can someone please suggest how to define Ackermann in Coq?

Comment: I ran into the same problem today. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand It's been a while... I provided a solution with `Program Fixpoint` below. Did you find a solution with `Function`?

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like `Function` can't solve this problem. However, its cousin `Program Fixpoint` can.

Let's define some lemmas treating well-foundedness first:

```
Require Import Coq.Program.Wf.
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Definition lexicographic_ordering (ab1 ab2 : nat * nat) : Prop :=
  match ab1, ab2 with
  | (a1, b1), (a2, b2) => 
      (a1 < a2) \/ ((a1 = a2) /\ (b1 < b2))
  end.

(* this is defined in stdlib, but unfortunately it is opaque *)
Lemma lt_wf_ind :
  forall n (P:nat -> Prop), (forall n, (forall m, m < n -> P m) -> P n) -> P n.
Proof. intro p; intros; elim (lt_wf p); auto with arith. Defined.

(* this is defined in stdlib, but unfortunately it is opaque too *)
Lemma lt_wf_double_ind :
  forall P:nat -> nat -> Prop,
    (forall n m,
      (forall p (q:nat), p < n -> P p q) ->
      (forall p, p < m -> P n p) -> P n m) -> forall n m, P n m.
Proof.
  intros P Hrec p. pattern p. apply lt_wf_ind.
  intros n H q. pattern q. apply lt_wf_ind. auto.
Defined.

Lemma lexicographic_ordering_wf : well_founded lexicographic_ordering.
Proof.
  intros (a, b); pattern a, b; apply lt_wf_double_ind.
  intros m n H1 H2.
  constructor; intros (m', n') [G | [-> G]].
  - now apply H1.
  - now apply H2.
Defined.
```

Now we can define the Ackermann-Péter function:

```
Program Fixpoint ack (ab : nat * nat) {wf lexicographic_ordering ab} : nat :=
  match ab with
  | (0, b) => b + 1
  | (S a, 0) => ack (a, 1)
  | (S a, S b) => ack (a, ack (S a, b))
  end.
Next Obligation.
  inversion Heq_ab; subst. left; auto. Defined.
Next Obligation.
  apply lexicographic_ordering_wf. Defined.
```

Some simple tests demonstrating that we can compute with `ack`:

```
Example test1 : ack (1, 2) = 4 := eq_refl.
Example test2 : ack (3, 4) = 125 := eq_refl.  (* this may take several seconds *)
```

---

Using the [Equations](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/) plugin by M. Sozeau and C. Mangin it is possible to define the function this way:

```
From Equations Require Import Equations Subterm.

Equations ack (p : nat * nat) : nat :=
ack p by rec p (lexprod _ _ lt lt) :=
ack (pair 0 n) := n + 1;
ack (pair (S m) 0) := ack (m, 1);
ack (pair (S m) (S n)) := ack (m, ack (S m, n)).
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use the `( , )` notation for pairs due to [issue #81](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations/issues/81). The code is taken from Equation's test suite: [ack.v](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations/blob/71b3b266563b18b47a8bd2677e65e94f08674283/test-suite/ack.v).

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because you are referencing the `ack` function while you are defining it. Self reference is only allowed in `Fixpoint`s (ie. recursive functions) but the problem is, as you probably know, that the Ackermann function is not a primitive recursive function.

See [Coq'Art section 4.3.2.2](http://books.google.nl/books?id=m5w5PRj5Nj4C&pg=PA95) for some more information on this.

So one alternative way to define it is by inlining a second recursive function that is structurally recursive for the second argument; so something like

```
Fixpoint ack (n m : nat) : nat :=
  match n with
  | O => S m
  | S p => let fix ackn (m : nat) :=
               match m with
               | O => ack p 1
               | S q => ack p (ackn q)
               end
           in ackn m
  end.
```

Comment: I wasn't using Fixpoint, but Function. This is supposed to work with total functions that have a decreasing argument, and I should be able to do so using either a measure or a comparison, followed by a theorem that arguments in recursive calls either have a smaller measure or are less than the original arguments, as per the comparator. I know Ackermann is 2nd-order PR, but obviously the PR status of the function didn't prevent you from encoding it in some way. What I'm wondering about is what is wrong with the encoding I gave, which seems to follow the description in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your function with Coq 8.4, and the error is slightly different:

```
Error: Nested recursive function are not allowed with Function
```

I guess the inner call to ack is the problem, but I don't know why.

Hope this helps a bit,
V.

PS: The usual way I define Ack is what wires wrote, with an inner fixpoint.