# What's the difference between Program Fixpoint and Function in Coq?

Tags: coq, totality

They seem to serve similar purposes. The one difference I've noticed so far is that while `Program Fixpoint` will accept a compound measure like `{measure (length l1 + length l2) }`, `Function` seems to reject this and will only allow `{measure length l1}`.

Is `Program Fixpoint` strictly more powerful than `Function`, or are they better suited for different use cases?

Comment: Incidentally, the [Coq v8.7 roadmap](https://github.com/coq/roadmaps/blob/master/text/roadmap-8.7.md#implementation-cleanups) says their implementations are going to be merged.

Comment: This is a good question, I recommend going to Coq's gitter if you need a detailed answer as the people knowledgeable about it don't read SO AFAIK; the implementation of Function and Program were done by different persons and in different contexts so indeed their set of features is not strictly a subset of the other. There are plans to merge both on them in a new "Equations" plugin, but that won't happen in 8.7, even if a lot of progress has been made. That being said, I think that you would usually better off with Program if you care about compatibility with future Coq releases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be a complete list, but it is what I have found so far:

- As you already mentioned, `Program Fixpoint` allows the measure to  look at more than one argument.
- `Function` creates a `foo_equation` lemma that can be used to rewrite calls to `foo` with its RHS. Very useful to avoid problems like [Coq simpl for Program Fixpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36329256/946226).
- In some (simple?) cases, `Function` can define a `foo_ind` lemma to perform induction along the structure of recursive calls of `foo`. Again, very useful to prove things about `foo` without effectively repeating the termination argument in the proof.
- `Program Fixpoint` can be tricked into supporting nested recursion, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46859452/946226. This is also why `Program Fixpoint` can [define the Ackermann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292421/error-in-defining-ackermann-in-coq) function when `Function` cannot.

Comment: It also seems impossible to define the Ackermann function with `Function`, but `Program Fixpoint` [can do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292421/error-in-defining-ackermann-in-coq).

Comment: Thanks, added that to the answer.