# Nested recursion and `Program Fixpoint` or `Function`

Tags: recursion, coq, isabelle, termination

I’d like to define the following function using `Program Fixpoint` or `Function` in Coq:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.
Require Import Coq.Program.Wf.
Require Import Recdef.

Inductive Tree := Node : nat -> list Tree -> Tree.

Fixpoint height (t : Tree) : nat :=
  match t with
   | Node x ts => S (fold_right Nat.max 0 (map height ts))
  end.

Program Fixpoint mapTree (f : nat -> nat) (t : Tree)  {measure (height t)} : Tree :=
  match t with 
    Node x ts => Node (f x) (map (fun t => mapTree f t) ts)
  end.
Next Obligation.
```

Unfortunately, at this point I have a proof obligation `height t < height (Node x ts)` without knowing that `t` is a member of `ts`.

Similarly with `Function` instead of `Program Fixpoint`, only that `Function` detects the problem and aborts the definition:

> ```
> Error:
> the term fun t : Tree => mapTree f t can not contain a recursive call to mapTree
> ```

I would expect to get a proof obligation of `In t ts → height t < height (Node x ts)`.

Is there a way of getting that that does not involve restructuring the function definition? (I know work-arounds that require inlining the definition of `map` here, for example – I’d like to avoid these.)

#### Isabelle

To justify that expectation, let me show what happens when I do the same in Isabelle, using the `function` command, which is (AFAIK) related to Coq’s `Function` command:

```
theory Tree imports Main begin

datatype Tree = Node nat "Tree list"

fun height where
  "height (Node _ ts) = Suc (foldr max (map height ts) 0)"

function mapTree where
  "mapTree f (Node x ts) = Node (f x) (map (λ t. mapTree f t) ts)"
by pat_completeness auto

termination
proof (relation "measure (λ(f,t). height t)")
  show "wf (measure (λ(f, t). height t))" by auto
next
  fix f :: "nat ⇒ nat" and x :: nat  and ts :: "Tree list" and t
  assume "t ∈ set ts"
  thus "((f, t), (f, Node x ts))  ∈ measure (λ(f, t). height t)"
    by (induction ts) auto
qed
```

In the termination proof, I get the assumption `t ∈ set ts`.

Note that Isabelle does not require a manual termination proof here, and the following definition works just fine:

```
fun mapTree where
  "mapTree f (Node x ts) = Node (f x) (map (λ t. mapTree f t) ts)"
```

This works because the `map` function has a “congruence lemma” of the form

```
xs = ys ⟹ (⋀x. x ∈ set ys ⟹ f x = g x) ⟹ map f xs = map g ys
```

that the `function` command uses to find out that the termination proof only needs to consider `t ∈ set ts`..

If such a lemma is not available, e.g. because I define

```
definition "map' = map"
```

and use that in `mapTree`, I get the same unprovable proof obligation as in Coq. I can make it work again by declaring a congruence lemma for `map'`, e.g. using

```
declare map_cong[folded map'_def,fundef_cong]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it might be advisable to avoid this problem. But if one really wants to obtain the proof obligation that Isabelle gives you, here is a way:

In Isabelle, we can give an external lemma that stats that `map` applies its arguments only to members of the given list. In Coq, we cannot do this in an external lemma, but we can do it in the type. So instead of the normal type of map

```
forall A B, (A -> B) -> list A -> list B
```

we want the type to say “`f` is only ever applied to elements of the list:

```
forall A B (xs : list A), (forall x : A, In x xs -> B) -> list B
```

(It requires reordering the argument so that the type of `f` can mention `xs`).

Writing this function is not trivial, and I found it easier to use a proof script:

```
Definition map {A B} (xs : list A) (f : forall (x:A), In x xs -> B) : list B.
Proof.
  induction xs.
  * exact [].
  * refine (f a _ :: IHxs _).
    - left. reflexivity.
    - intros. eapply f. right. eassumption.
Defined.
```

But you can also write it “by hand”:

```
Fixpoint map {A B} (xs : list A) : forall (f : forall (x:A), In x xs -> B), list B :=
  match xs with
   | [] => fun _ => []
   | x :: xs => fun f => f x (or_introl eq_refl) :: map xs (fun y h => f y (or_intror h))
  end.
```

In either case, the result is nice: I can use this function in `mapTree`, i.e.

```
Program Fixpoint mapTree (f : nat -> nat) (t : Tree)  {measure (height t)} : Tree :=
  match t with 
    Node x ts => Node (f x) (map ts (fun t _ => mapTree f t))
  end.
Next Obligation.
```

and I don’t have to do anything with the new argument to `f`, but it shows up in the the termination proof obligation, as `In t ts → height t < height (Node x ts)` as desired. So I can prove that and define `mapTree`:

```
  simpl.
  apply Lt.le_lt_n_Sm.
  induction ts; inversion_clear H.
  - subst. apply PeanoNat.Nat.le_max_l.
  - rewrite IHts by assumption.
    apply PeanoNat.Nat.le_max_r.
Qed.
```

It only works with `Program Fixpoint`, not with `Function`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, you actually do not need well-founded recursion in its full generality:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Set Implicit Arguments.

Inductive tree := Node : nat -> list tree -> tree.

Fixpoint map_tree (f : nat -> nat) (t : tree) : tree :=
  match t with
  | Node x ts => Node (f x) (map (fun t => map_tree f t) ts)
  end.
```

Coq is able to figure out by itself that recursive calls to `map_tree` are performed on strict subterms. However, proving anything about this function is difficult, as the induction principle generated for `tree` is not useful:

```
tree_ind : 
  forall P : tree -> Prop, 
    (forall (n : nat) (l : list tree), P (Node n l)) ->
    forall t : tree, P t
```

This is essentially the same problem you described earlier.  Luckily, we can fix the issue by proving our own induction principle with a proof term.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Unset Elimination Schemes.
Inductive tree := Node : nat -> list tree -> tree.
Set Elimination Schemes.

Fixpoint tree_ind
  (P : tree -> Prop)
  (IH : forall (n : nat) (ts : list tree),
          fold_right (fun t => and (P t)) True ts ->
          P (Node n ts))
  (t : tree) : P t :=
  match t with
  | Node n ts =>
    let fix loop ts :=
      match ts return fold_right (fun t' => and (P t')) True ts with
      | [] => I
      | t' :: ts' => conj (tree_ind P IH t') (loop ts')
      end in
    IH n ts (loop ts)
  end.

Fixpoint map_tree (f : nat -> nat) (t : tree) : tree :=
  match t with
  | Node x ts => Node (f x) (map (fun t => map_tree f t) ts)
  end.
```

The `Unset Elimination Schemes` command prevents Coq from generating its default (and not useful) induction principle for `tree`.  The occurrence of `fold_right` on the induction hypothesis simply expresses that the predicate `P` holds of every tree `t'` appearing in `ts`.

Here is a statement that you can prove using this induction principle:

```
Lemma map_tree_comp f g t :
  map_tree f (map_tree g t) = map_tree (fun n => f (g n)) t.
Proof.
  induction t as [n ts IH]; simpl; f_equal.
  induction ts as [|t' ts' IHts]; try easy.
  simpl in *.
  destruct IH as [IHt' IHts'].
  specialize (IHts IHts').
  now rewrite IHt', <- IHts.
Qed.
```

Comment: “In this case, you actually do not need well-founded recursion in its full generality” I guess I simplified the example too much. It works because `map` is carefully defined with a local fixpoint, right, and the termination checker sees through that. What if I recurse under something not as well behaved, and I really need well-founded recursion?

Comment: Also, thanks for `Unset Elimination Schemes` – does that somehow makes Coq pick up `tree_ind` when you do `induction t`?

Comment: Coq always picks foo_ind for performing induction on an inductive type named foo.

Comment: Ha, that's cute, and good to know. Are there obfuscated Coq proof contests?

Answer (score 5):

You can now do this with Equations and get the right elimination principle automatically, using either [structural nested recursion](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/examples/Examples.nested_mut_rec.html) or [well-founded recursion](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/examples/Examples.RoseTree.html)

Comment: I like how the definition of `map_In` does not require proofs as in my answer! Although I don’t understand why – how is the `_` in the argument to the recursive call to `map_In` resolved? (Presumably to the term `or_intror H`.)

Comment: Holes are filled automatically using the program_simpl tactic which calls auto here, I guess that's enough to resolve them. Otherwise you get proof obligations, no magic, the proofs are still there!