# Program Fixpoint: recursive call in `let` and hypothesis of the obligation

Tags: coq, totality

Say I have the following `Program Fixpoint`:

```
From Coq Require Import List Program.
Import ListNotations.

Program Fixpoint f l {measure (length l)}: list nat :=
let f_rec := (f (tl l) ) in
match hd_error l with
| Some n => n :: f_rec
| None => []
end.
```

(This example basically returns `l` in a very stupid way, for the sake of having a simple example).

Here, I have a recursive call to `f` (stored in `f_rec`) which is only used if `l` contains an element, which ensures that when I use `f_rec`, `length (tl l)` is indeed smaller than `length l`.

However, when I want to solve the obligation

```
Next Obligation.
```

I don't have the hypothesis `hd_error l = Some n` which I need.

(Somehow, I have the impression that it is understood as "compute `f (tl l)` at the `let in` place", and not "delay the computation until it is actually used").

---

To illustrate the difference, if I "inline" the `let ... in` statement:

```
Program Fixpoint f l {measure (length l)}: list nat :=
match hd_error l with
| Some n => n ::  (f (tl l) )
| None => []
end.

Next Obligation.
destruct l.
```

Here I have `Heq_anonymous : Some n = hd_error []` in the environment.

---

My question is the following:
is it possible to have the hypothesis I need, i.e. to have the hypothesis generated by the `match ... with` statement ?

N.B.: Moving the `let` is a solution, but I am curious to know whether this is possible without doing so. For instance, it might be useful in the case `f_rec` is used in various contexts, to avoid duplicating `f (tl l)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick is to explicitly ask for the hypothesis you need (I recently saw it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46859452/2747511) by [Joachim Breitner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946226/joachim-breitner)):

```
let f_rec := fun pf : length (tl l) < length l => f (tl l) in
```

This way you will be able to use `f_rec` only when it makes sense.

```
Program Fixpoint f l {measure (length l)}: list nat :=
  let f_rec := fun pf : length (tl l) < length l => f (tl l) in
  match hd_error l with
  | Some n => n :: f_rec _
  | None => []
  end.
Next Obligation. destruct l; [discriminate | auto]. Qed.
```

Comment: Whao, this tip is pretty nice !