# Teach coq to check termination

Tags: coq, termination, totality

Coq, unlike many others, accepts an optional explicit parameter,which can be used to indicate the decreasing structure of a fixpoint definition.

From Gallina specification, 1.3.4,

```
Fixpoint ident params {struct ident0 } : type0 := term0
```

defines the syntax. but from it, we've known that it must be an identifier, instead of a general measure.

However, in general, there are recursive functions, that the termination is not quite obvious,or it in fact is, but just difficult for the termination checker to find a decreasing structure. For example, following program interleaves two lists,

```
Fixpoint interleave (A : Set) (l1 l2 : list A) : list A :=
  match l1 with
  | [] => []
  | h :: t => h :: interleave l2 t
  end
```

This function clearly terminates, while Coq just couldn't figure it out. The reason is neither `l1` nor `l2` are decreasing every cycle. But what if we consider a measure, defined to be `length l1 + length l2`? Then this measure clearly decreases every recursion.

So my question is, in the case of sophisticated situation, where code is not straightforward to be organized in a termination checkable way, how do you educate coq and convince it to accept the fixpoint definition?

Comment: Are you asking about the tools you can use to convince Coq your function terminates? Or something else? Like how to do that with `Fixpoint` or the `fix` primitive?

Comment: @AntonTrunov I'm asking if I can prove a function terminates, how can I teach it to coq, if possible. for the sake of the example, how can I let coq to accept this interleave definition, without changing the basic idea of the algorithm?

Comment: Would you consider using `Program Fixpoint` / `Function` / `Fix` combinator   / `Equations` plugin as a solution? Using those tools adds an extra parameter to your function whose purpose is to convince Coq your function is terminating.

Comment: @AntonTrunov I'm not aware of these. Will take a look.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have multiple options and all of them boil down to structural recursion in the end.

## Preamble

```
From Coq Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.
Set Implicit Arguments.
```

## Structural recursion

Sometimes you can reformulate your algorithm in a structurally recursive way:

```
Fixpoint interleave1 {A} (l1 l2 : list A) {struct l1} : list A :=
  match l1, l2 with
  | [], _ => l2
  | _, [] => l1
  | h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2 => h1 :: h2 :: interleave1 t1 t2
  end.
```

Incidentally, in some cases you can use a trick with nested `fix`es -- see [this definition of Ackermann function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10303475/2747511) (it wouldn't work with just `Fixpoint`).

## `Program Fixpoint`

You can use `Program Fixpoint` mechanism which lets you write your program naturally and later prove that it always terminates.

```
From Coq Require Import Program Arith.

Program Fixpoint interleave2 {A} (l1 l2 : list A) 
  {measure (length l1 + length l2)} : list A :=
  match l1 with
  | [] => l2
  | h :: t => h :: interleave2 l2 t
  end.
Next Obligation. simpl; rewrite Nat.add_comm; trivial with arith. Qed.
```

## `Function`

Another option is to use the `Function` command which can be somewhat limited compared to `Program Fixpoint`. You can find out more about their differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606245/2747511).

```
From Coq Require Recdef.

Definition sum_len {A} (ls : (list A * list A)) : nat :=
  length (fst ls) + length (snd ls).

Function interleave3 {A} (ls : (list A * list A))
  {measure sum_len ls} : list A :=
  match ls with
  | ([], _) => []
  | (h :: t, l2) => h :: interleave3 (l2, t)
  end.
Proof.
  intros A ls l1 l2 h t -> ->; unfold sum_len; simpl; rewrite Nat.add_comm; trivial with arith.
Defined.
```

## [Equations](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/) plugin

This is an external plugin which addresses many issues with defining functions in Coq, including dependent types and termination.

```
From Equations Require Import Equations.

Equations interleave4 {A} (l1 l2 : list A) : list A :=
interleave4 l1 l2 by rec (length l1 + length l2) lt :=
interleave4 nil l2 := l2;
interleave4 (cons h t) l2 := cons h (interleave4 l2 t).
Next Obligation. rewrite Nat.add_comm; trivial with arith. Qed.
```

The code above works if you apply [this fix](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations/pull/44).

## `Fix` / `Fix_F_2` combinators

You can learn more about this (manual) approach if you follow the links from [this  question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42285235/2747511) about `mergeSort` function. By the way, the `mergeSort` function can be defined without using `Fix` if you apply the nested `fix` trick I mentioned earlier. Here is a solution which uses  `Fix_F_2` combinator since we have two arguments and not one like `mergeSort`:

```
Definition ordering {A} (l1 l2 : list A * list A) : Prop :=
  length (fst l1) + length (snd l1) < length (fst l2) + length (snd l2).

Lemma ordering_wf' {A} : forall (m : nat) (p : list A * list A),
    length (fst p) + length (snd p) <= m -> Acc (@ordering A) p.
Proof.
  unfold ordering; induction m; intros p H; constructor; intros p'.
  - apply Nat.le_0_r, Nat.eq_add_0 in H as [-> ->].
    intros contra%Nat.nlt_0_r; contradiction.
  - intros H'; eapply IHm, Nat.lt_succ_r, Nat.lt_le_trans; eauto.
Defined.

Lemma ordering_wf {A} : well_founded (@ordering A).
Proof. now red; intro ; eapply ordering_wf'. Defined.

(* it's in the stdlib but unfortunately opaque -- this blocks evaluation *)
Lemma destruct_list {A} (l : list A) :
  { x:A & {tl:list A | l = x::tl} } + { l = [] }.
Proof.
  induction l as [|h tl]; [right | left]; trivial.
  exists h, tl; reflexivity.
Defined.

Definition interleave5 {A} (xs ys : list A) : list A.
  refine (Fix_F_2 (fun _ _ => list A)
    (fun (l1 l2 : list A)
       (interleave : (forall l1' l2', ordering (l1', l2') (l1, l2) -> list A)) =>
       match destruct_list l1 with
       | inright _ => l2
       | inleft pf => let '(existT _ h (exist _ tl eq)) := pf in
                     h :: interleave l2 tl _
       end) (ordering_wf (xs,ys))).
Proof. unfold ordering; rewrite eq, Nat.add_comm; auto.
Defined.
```

## Evaluation tests

```
Check eq_refl : interleave1 [1;2;3] [4;5;6] = [1;4;2;5;3;6].
Check eq_refl : interleave2 [1;2;3] [4;5;6] = [1;4;2;5;3;6].
Check eq_refl : interleave3 ([1;2;3], [4;5;6]) = [1;4;2;5;3;6].
Fail Check eq_refl : interleave4 [1;2;3] [4;5;6] = [1;4;2;5;3;6]. (* Equations plugin *)
Check eq_refl : interleave5 [1;2;3] [4;5;6] = [1;4;2;5;3;6].
```

Exercise: what happens with this last check if you comment out `destruct_list` lemma?

Comment: thank god, this is such a well and concise educational writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called a `measure` instead of a structural argument for termination. For this, I believe you have to use the `Program Fixpoint` mechanism, which is a little involved and will make your proofs look uglier (because it generates a structural recursion out of the proof that you provide, so that the function you will actually use is not quite the function you wrote).

Details here:
https://coq.inria.fr/refman/program.html

It also seems like something called `Equations` can deal with measures?
cf. http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/examples/RoseTree.html
https://www.irif.fr/~sozeau/research/coq/equations.en.html